# Hide vertices in a mesh

Tags: vertices

Blender 2.9

I'm working on a big mesh and I would like to hide the "big black dots" (vertices) of the mesh.

For the Edge for example I can do it in the viewport overlays

[image]

[image]

But for the vertices I didn't find an option to do somethig similar...

Visualy, what I would like to have is something like this (capture from another forum, another program):

[image]

in the selected region, the vertices are not marked as dots. That's what I would like to get.

Edit: I do not need to hide the vertices in an specific region. The image is only to show the diference between vertices as "big dots" VS vertices only "as interception of edges", which is what I want. Just hide them or make them really really small...

I hope this is posible to do.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I might be wrong, but to make it short the answer is "no". You can hide vertices with H like edge or faces as well, but hiding the vertices means all edges and faces that are using these vertices will be hidden, too. And I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: By the way, the dots are showing the vertices themselves. The overlay settings for edges and faces to not hide them, they are still visible. You can only disable if they are highlighted when selected and if the crease/sharp/bevel/seam marked edges should be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for all those explanations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to preferences -> Themes -> set vertex size to 1

[image]

Comment: This is the closer answer to what I was looking for... Which I see, after this discussion, can be synthetize to: "I want the vertices to be very small or dissapear"

Comment: Thus, it seems that what I wanted to do is simply not possible (as said by Gordon before). Then, if I don't get any other answer in the comming days, I will mark this one as the solution. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Do you still need to manipulate vertices? If not you could just use edge/face mode, keys <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd>?

Seems too simple to be the answer!

Comment: I might have gotten the question wrong, but I think the wish is to be able to keep working in Vertex Select mode and only remove the dots in certain regions.

Comment: Indeed, I need manipulate de vertices. However, I do not need to hide the "big black dots" for an specific region. I'm sorry if the image I put has made you think that.

Comment: Okay, then the answer @Chris gave is as good as it gets I guess, at least until there comes a Blender version where you can disable the dots.

Answer (score 0):

One way, if it's not too painful, is to work in a Cycles rendered preview:

[image]

Then we can select any vertices we don't want to see and hide them-- Cycles will still draw all the faces.  Note that this has all of the other effects of hiding as well, the vertices are unselectable and won't be affected by proportional editing (maybe other stuff too.)

Of course, this is at the cost of a raytrace-speed preview.  Still, even though I generally work in Eevee, I sometimes break this out so that I can see how a proportional edit is going to affect an entire mesh, while having some vertices hidden to prevent them from being affected by the edit.  Shrink/fatten on knife-cut cloth wrinkles is where this comes up a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. Maybe too complex for the purpose of my question, but very helpful for sure for further work.